# Installing Ubuntu I get: please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

I've downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and 9.04 - Desktop, respectively and burned a them on separate DVD and CD.

But when I run `setup.exe` or booting from drive `E:` I get a welcome display, choose language, then *Install Ubuntu* but got this error message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

How should I go about installing Ubuntu bypassing all this?

Comment: You need to download the 32bit version.

Comment: I thank you for your support, but now as I've burned the 32 bit on a dvd and it has taken over 3 hour installing Ubuntu (Copying files...). What do you suggest, should I shut down the system or wait? Or there another way where I could take out the disc and put it back?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your computer is set up to run a 32 bit operating system. You need to download the 32-bit (i386) version of Ubuntu in order for it to work with your hardware. 32-bit is more common on older machines.